# How to calculate Impedance of Edge Coupled Stripline Coplanar Waveguide

Tags: emc, high-speed

I have some questions about adding copper pour on signal layers with high-speed differential pairs traces.
I am routing my HDMI diff pair traces on an inner layer. because we have been having some issues passing radiated emission tests, a colleague suggested for the next board revision to add on all signal layers copper fill to essentially create a waveguide around the diff pair as illustrated below.

[image]

- How can I calculate the impedance of stripline waveguide? I haven't been able to find any calculators online that have that configuration
- Is this even a good idea?

Comment: About calculating part: there is atlc utility/program http://atlc.sourceforge.net/ which can numerically solve arbitrary layout.

Comment: Adding such a ground pour may not help much. You should look for the root cause of the EMC issues. Look for return current continuities (both for diff and common signals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ground pour between the two signal traces, you no longer have edge-coupled differential stripline.

If you want edge-coupled differential stripline, remove the ground pour from between the signal traces, and keep the other ground pour at least 5 or 10 trace widths away from the outside edges of the stripline traces.

If you insist on retaining the ground between the signal traces, then you could calculate the characteristic impedance of each signal trace individually as a single-ended stripline. However if the ground pour is closer than 5 or 10 trace widths it will change the characteristic impedance relative to the values given by the simpler calculators.

You can calculate the characteristic impedance of the differential pair using an online calculator, a dedicated transmission line calculator like Polar, or a 2-1/2 or 3-D EM simulator like Ansys or HFSS. You will likely need to use an EM simulator if you want to account for ground pours near the signal traces.

> Is this even a good idea?

A ground pour with a large keep-out distance away from the stripline traces is a good idea. Even a ring of ground around the outside edge of the board with stitching vias to the other ground layers would likely give 90% of the improvement in radiated emisisons of a full ground pour.

But generally if the strip-lines are routed between continuous ground planes (i.e., there are no slots in the upper and lower ground planes), it is not likely a dominant source of radiated emissions. If your radiation problem is happening at (multiples of) frequencies corresponding to what's carried on these striplines, look to things like power supply decoupling at the driver chip, trace length matching for the differential pair, termination at the end of the stripline, etc. before assuming your stripline itself is radiating.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't have to have ground pour between the traces. About your other point, the problem we have is that stripline is referenced to a GND and PWR plane and the traces are crossing some slots on the power plane, essentially disrupting the return paths for currents. So we are instead changing this to ensure we are sandwiching the striplines between GND planes. We are indeed failing at the fundamental, but also the multiple harmonics of the fundamental. I suspect the return path and the use of multiple vias are exacerbating the EMI.

Comment: What frequency? Can you put capacitors between the two power nets near the power plane slots?

Comment: 148MHz, 296MHz, 216MHz, 448MHz, 593MHz, 891MHz...Putting capacitors would be difficult because these are inner layer planes

Comment: Even if you have to run vias up to a surface layer and place the capacitors there, it will provide a way for return currents from your transmission lines to get across that slot without making a big loop (and generating radiation). Alternately, you could place decoupling caps from each power net to ground as near the slot as possible.